# How can I set a default value to show for a taxonomy term name in its edit form?

Tags: forms, 9

I have a site where I have a taxonomy term. I want to set a default value to the term name and display it when the form loads.
In `hook_form_alter()`, I tried to set the default value to *Check term name* in the form. The form loads with this value, but even after changing the value in the text field, the form gets submitted with *Check term name*.

This is the code I am using to set the default value.

```php
$form['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'check term name';
```

How do I set the default value?

Comment: You can't set #value, it should be #default_value.

Comment: But how come user can see this default value in the form? I want to prepopulate the title field with something and change the value according to what the user provides.

Comment: That's exactly what default values are for, is there a reason you can't use them?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin and @Clive noted, you must use `#default_value` to do this.

```
$form['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'check term name';
```

> [Property] #default_value:
>
> **Description:** The value of the form element that will be displayed or
> selected initially if the form has not been submitted yet. **Should NOT
> be confused with #value**, which is a hard-coded value the user cannot
> change!
>
> Source: [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#default_value)

(Yes, this is a reference page for D7, but this section still applies.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.